# How can the user sort the price?

Tags: php, html

This is the part of my code, i'm just a student from college who are struggling with the assignment. This is for the product list page which are allow the user to sort the product price (proPrice) and also the newest or oldest product by the proID.

```
<?php
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                        $output = '<div class="col-md-4 ">
                       <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                         <img class="item_title" style="width:100%;height:225%;" src="' . $row['proImg'] . ' ">
                       <div  class="card-body">
                        <div  style="text-align: center;">
                       <p><b class="item_name" id="s">' . $row['proName'] . '</b><br>
                       <small class="item_color" id="s">' . $row['proColor'] . '</small></p>
                      </div>
                        <p class="item_price" style="font-size:20px;" > RM' . $row['proPrice'] . '
                         </p>
                    <form style="padding:10px;margin-top:5px;" action="proDesc.php">
                     <button style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add to Cart
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cart-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
                  </svg>
                 </button>
               </form>
                <form style="padding:10px;margin-top:5px;" action="proDesc.php" >
                 <input type="hidden" name="name" class="item_id" value="' . $row['proID'] . '">
                <button type="submit" style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View</button>
                 </form></div></div></div>';
                        echo $output;
                        
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: How and when does the user select this sorting criteria? Do they submit their choice in a form or does this need to happen on the result page, without refreshing? Can there be multiple (for example, both by price and id)?

Comment: the user can sort the price by click on the button but for the id is radio button..I just put onclick, i'm not sure is it work. I hope that the result is happen on the page without refreshing...currently,  both of them can be selected..but i'm not sure how to let them just can select either one

Comment: Create a REST endpoint that returns the sorted products, and then write some JavaScript that uses the REST endpoint to add the sorted products. You can use this sort function to do the sorting https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort in your REST endpoint to get the sorting you want.